# Refreshing an Excel Pivot table from C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to refresh a pivot table in an Excel sheet and get the following exception:

```
Item method in the PivotTables class failed
```

Heres the code:

```
pivotSheet.Activate();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = 
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables)pivotSheet.PivotTables(missing);
int pivotTablesCount = pivotTables.Count;  
    if (pivotTablesCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= pivotTablesCount; i++)
        {
            pivotTables.Item(i).RefreshTable(); //The Item method throws an exception
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the indexing starts at zero you will overrun the collection with your loop.

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pivotTablesCount; i++)
```

If that doesn't work Excel probably starts indexing at 1 not at 0.

Try:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pivotTablesCount; i++)
```

Comment: starting at i = 1. Did the Trick. I think indexes in excel start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Hi Richard, I realise your post was 5 years ago, but I currently have a question around the area of Pivot Tables and therefore was wondering if you could take a quick look? Any help will be appreciated, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623752/detect-pivot-table-in-microsoft-excel-using-interop-c-sharp

Comment: @Alex Sure I'll take a look, this answer look promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35631705/467720

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks Richard, you are right, it solved my issue, many thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will help you it's working.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets;
        
oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
oXL.Visible = true;
oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
//Get all the sheets in the workbook
mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet pivotSheet in mWorkSheets)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = pivotSheet.PivotTables();
    int pivotTablesCount = pivotTables.Count;
    if (pivotTablesCount > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= pivotTablesCount; i++)
        {
            pivotTables.Item(i).RefreshTable(); //The Item method throws an exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void RefreshSheets(string filePath)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbooks xlWorkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlWorkbooks.Open(filePath);

        foreach (Excel.Worksheet xlworksheet in xlWorkbook.Worksheets)
        {
            Excel.PivotTables pivotTbls = (Excel.PivotTables)xlworksheet.PivotTables(Type.Missing);
            if (pivotTbls.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= pivotTbls.Count; j++)
                {
                    pivotTbls.Item(i).RefreshTable();
                }
            }
        }
        xlWorkbook.Save();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        xlWorkbook.Close(0);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbooks);
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
```

Add using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; in using