# Detect pivot table in Microsoft Excel using Interop c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to detect whether a cell in Microsoft excel contains a Pivot Table by using Microsoft Interop c#

What I want to do is loop through all of the cells as indicated in the code below, and then if the cell contains a pivot table, I want to store the row and column information of that cell in an integer value as such:

```
int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

Excel.Range cell = null;

for (int iRow = 1; iRow < rowCount; iRow++)
{
    for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= colCount; iCol++)
    {
        /* This line of code is probably wrong */
        cell = xlRange.Cells[iRow, iCol] as Excel.Range;

        if(/*Cell contains PivotTable*/)
        {
            int rowLocation = iRow;
            int colLocation = iCol;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable_methods.aspx) and other sources but can't seem to find any methods for detecting if a cell contains a pivot table.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some code for reference. 
Identify the overall Range occupied by PivotTables in the sheet and validate whether the cell is a part of the Range.

```cs
private Excel.Range IdentifyPivotRanges(Excel.Range xlRange)
{
    Excel.Range pivotRanges = null;
    Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = xlRange.Worksheet.PivotTables();
    int pivotCount = pivotTables.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pivotCount; i++)
    {
        Excel.Range tmpRange = xlRange.Worksheet.PivotTables(i).TableRange2;
        if (pivotRanges == null) pivotRanges = tmpRange;
        pivotRanges = this.Application.Union(pivotRanges, tmpRange);
    }
    return pivotRanges;
}

private void CheckCellsForPivot(Excel.Range xlRange)
{
    Excel.Range pivotRange = IdentifyPivotRanges(xlRange);
    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
    int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
    for (int iRow = 1; iRow <= rowCount; iRow++)
    {
        for (int iCol = 1; iCol <= colCount; iCol++)
        {
            var cell = xlRange.Cells[iRow, iCol];
            if (Application.Intersect(pivotRange, cell) != null)
            {
                int rowLocation = iRow;
                int colLocation = iCol;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with a little bit of tweaking this solution solved my issue

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing, I, like Trebblez was not able to find a clear answer in the documentation, or anywhere else for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

look here is got a couple of examples about looping through Pivot tables list

```
pivotSheet.Activate();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables pivotTables = 
        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTables)pivotSheet.PivotTables(missing);
int pivotTablesCount = pivotTables.Count;
```

[Refreshing an Excel Pivot table from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141906/refreshing-an-excel-pivot-table-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I already took a look at this, But I couldn't make sense of obtaining the cell that contains a pivot table from using this, Could you put the answer in context of my question if possible please?

Comment: Each pivot table has a location.....    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.location.aspx...Pivot table members here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable_members.aspx. I also found this in my travels.. very nice at showing you all ranges for pivot tables http://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on CS's Answer:  I used CS's answer but with some modification so that all you need is the path to your WorkBook.  No range needed, just pass the worksheets within the workbook.

```
#region PivotTables

public static List<DataTable> PivotCollection(string filePath)
{
    List<DataTable> pivotCollection = new List<DataTable>();

    //Get Workbook
    xl.Application app = new xl.Application();
    xl.Workbook wb = null;
    wb = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

    //Loop through each worksheet and find pivot tables to add to collection
    foreach (xl.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
    {
        //Get range of pivot table
        string wsName = ws.Name.ToString();
        xl.Range pivotRange = GetPivotRange(ws);

        //Check if there is any table to add
        if (pivotRange == null) continue;
        DataTable pivotTable = DataTables.FromRange(pivotRange);

        //Get info from range and add to pivot
        pivotCollection.Add(pivotTable);

    }

    return pivotCollection;

}

//Find Pivot table in worksheet
//CS's Code with slight modification, use worksheet instead of range
public static xl.Range GetPivotRange(xl.Worksheet xlworkSheet)
{
    xl.Range pivotRanges = null;
    xl.PivotTables pivotTables = xlworkSheet.PivotTables();
    int pivotCount = pivotTables.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pivotCount; i++)
    {
        xl.Range tmpRange = xlworkSheet.PivotTables(i).TableRange2;
        if (pivotRanges == null) pivotRanges = tmpRange;
        pivotRanges = tmpRange;
    }
    return pivotRanges;
}
#endregion
```